# Handling the response sent from a ruby on rails application in wordpress

Tags: server, http

I am using my rails application to send data to a wordpress site. Basically if a user has wrong password, I am going to end the reverse proxy and redirect the user back to the wordpress site but I want to pass data along. In Rails, I use Net::HTTP to send data to another server:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Now in WordPress I'm not sure how to receive it.

thanks for response

Answer (score 1):

I think you're basically recreating what the [»JSON API Plugin«](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) already does. It should work hands in hands with your Ruby App without a problem and server all your normal as well as CPT tasks.

Comment: Actually now I am redirecting the user and passing data in query string. And so when it redirects to wordpress page, I want to just add a line of php: if ( isset($_GET['invalid_password']) echo "invalid password";  Is there a place i can put this line of code?

Comment: The wp-login.php has dozens of hooks - just take a look at it and search for `do_action` and `apply_filters`. Then hook into them from your functions.php file (or better from a custom plugin). Anyway: You might be better off, just taking the mentioned plugin.